# CountDowntimer is not constant, I would like a counter with a resolution below the millisecond

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have to set an ImageView background with a checkerboard exactly every 500ms but when I try to do this:

```
 new CountDown(60000, 500) {

        public void onTick() {
            if (flag==1){
               img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name1);
               list.add(System.nanoTime());
               flag=0;
            }else{
               img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name2);
               list.add(System.nanoTime());
               flag=1;
            }


        }

        public void onFinish() {
                writeToFile(list);
                finish();
        }
    }.start();
```

I see that the differences between the timestamps in my list are variables. How can I fix this problem? I would like that time to be constant.

Comment: You cannot get precise timing for doing UI work with the standard `View` hierarchy. Consider switching to a development environment that targets games, and you may have more options.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use Android to do this... I'm trying to create a video in order to have a precise frame rate...

Comment: "Unfortunately I have to use Android to do this" -- Android is an operating system. There are many ways to create apps for Android. "I'm trying to create a video in order to have a precise frame rate" -- I do not expect you to have much luck.

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: I would imagine that there are dedicated tools for creating animated videos that have little to do with Android but would give you far better results. Otherwise, consider switching to a development environment that targets games (e.g., Unity 3D).